# Prove equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I have the assignment:

> Provide a direct  proof of this statement: Let A and B be two arbitrary
>   sets such that B ⊆  A, and let R be an equivalence relation on A. Consider the relation
>   S = {(a, b) ∈ R  | a, b ∈  B} on the set B. Then  S is an equivalence relation on B (that
>   is, reflexive, symmetric and transitive).

Obviously i have to show that S is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
But how would this be done?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check the three defining properties in turn : (i) Refl : is $aSa$ ? Obviously $a \in B$ implies $a \in A$. But if $(a,a) \in R$ then $(a,a) \in R \text { and } a \in B$. Thus, by def, $(a,a) \in S$. And so on...

Comment: Can you prove e.g. that $(a,a)\in S$ for every $a\in B$? That already proves reflexivity. It is just a matter of definitions. Also for symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: Thanks. @Mauro, how does a being in B imply that (a,a) is in S? Can we assume that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a relation $R\subset A\times A$ of pairs of elements of $A$. $S$ however, is exactly those pairs in $R$ that have both elements in $B\subset A$.

Since $R$ is reflexive, for any $a\in A$ we have $(a,a)\in R$. In particular for any $b\in B\subset A$ we have $(b,b)\in R$. But this is a pair with both elements in $B$, so $(b,b)\in S$ for any $b\in B$. Therefore $S$ is reflexive.

Since $R$ is symmetric, if $(a,a')\in R$ for some $a,a'\in A$, then also $(a',a)\in R$. Now, if $(b,b')\in S\subset R$, then also $(b',b)\in R$ as $R$ is symmetric, but again $(b',b)$ is a pair with both elements in $B$, so $(b',b)\in S$, meaning that $S$ is symmetric.

For transitive, let $b,b',b''\in B\subset A$ and $(b,b')\in S$ and $(b',b'')\in S$. Then $(b,b')$ and $(b',b'')$ are both elements of $R$, since $S\subset R$. Therefore $(b,b'')\in R$, because $R$ is transitive. But this is a pair with both elements in $B$, so $(b,b'')\in S$. This shows that $S$ is transitive.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!